# How to detect the default phone number of a contact (if set)

Tags: android, android-contacts

ATM I get the number and label of a given CONTACT_ID with

```
String where =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId;
Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
     String number = Tools.getString(c, CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
     String label = Tools.getString(c,CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL);
}
```

Android has the ability to mark a given number as "default number". **How can I find out if the queried number is the default number?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to query for the column [IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY) in your CONTENT_URI query.

If it returns a non-zero value then the entry may be interpreted as the default contact value of its kind (for example, the default phone number to use for the contact).

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched some time for this. I wonder why the documentation is so imprecise here. But marking a number as default number when SUPER_PRIMARY > 0 seems to work fine! :-)