# Retrieving default number for contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have read [How to detect the default phone number of a contact (if set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474019/how-to-detect-the-default-phone-number-of-a-contact-if-set), but it seems that IS_SUPER_PRIMARY only works on some phones, is there a better solution to get the default number for a contact?

Comment: On which phones it doesn't work? Are the contacts stored on device or on SIM?

Comment: It worked on my galaxy nexus, but it seems that TouchWiz phones have trouble? (note 2, s3) It seems strange to me that there isn't a clear cut solution to this seemingly basic problem... Thank you for your interest

Comment: @RSenApps I think the problem is that they don't use primary but rather tags like mobile, fixed network etc. etc.

Comment: @Warpzit I was thinking something similar... But it must have some concept of a primary phone number, right?

Comment: No it does not. It has categories and the user select which to use on a case to case basis (everytime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this simply is one of those device dependent things. I'd use IS_SUPER_PRIMARY and when it returns nothing I'd just pick one from the list of numbers or let the user pick which to use. Alternatively you should look into which number from a list the user has used most often and use this as the primary.

Comment: Thanks for answering, if nobody has a better answer, I'll make sure to give you the bounty